# Error in latex document during writing an equation. 'Missing { inserted' and 'missing } inserted'

Tags: latex, equation

```
\begin{equation} df = \frac{(\frac{{s_\bar{n_1}}^2}{n_1} + \frac{{s_\bar{n_2}}^2}{n_2})^2}{\frac{{s_1}^4}{{{n_1}^2}(n_1 - 1)} + \frac{{s_2}^4}{{n_2}^2(n_2 - 1)}} \end{equation}
```

Comment: There's a separate Stackexchange site for TeX related things: https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Pro tip: whenever you encounter such an error from LaTeX, remove or comment out parts of your code until it starts working, then gradually add them back again until you've found the problem.

In this case, it's here:

```
s_\bar{n_1}
```

The part after the first `_` is more than a single token, so it needs some extra curly braces:

```
s_{\bar{n_1}}
```